# What does this binding log means?

Tags: .net, sharepoint, fuslogvw

I am getting assembly loading issues, and in VS getting this log, how would I know what's happening here, assembly is already in gac

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = FruitFactory.Features, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=993748c7d43a763c
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/Extensions/Microsoft/SharePoint/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SharePoint\VstspCache2484
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SharePoint\vssphost5.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: FruitFactory.Features, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=993748c7d43a763c
LOG: The same bind was seen before, and was failed with hr = 0x80070002.

========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: It probably means you need to put FruitFactory in the GAC.

Comment: Its already in gac - C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\FruitFactory.Features\v4.0_1.0.0.0__993748c7d43a763c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-installed VS 2012 and restarted the server, it fixed the issue for me...

Comment: and now I am getting same error but different dll for another solution and another dll which was working fine before, grr !!!!!